# Continuity proof of two-variable function.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, proof-verification

The Assignment

> Determine if the following function is continuous in $(0,0)$.
>
> $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{cases}
> \frac{x^2|y|^3}{x^2-xy+y^2}& , (x,y) \neq (0,0)
> \\
> 0& , (x,y) = (0,0)
> \end{cases}$$

My try:

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ x,y \neq 0$, then $$\frac{x^2|y|^3}{x^2-xy+y^2} < \frac{x^2|y|^3}{-xy} = -xy^2 \rightarrow 0 $$ $$\frac{x^2|y|^3}{x^2-xy+y^2} > 0$$ since $$x^2|y|^3 > 0, \ x^2-xy+y^2 > x^2-2xy+y^2 = (x-y)^2 > 0$$
>   The limit of $f$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ then follows from the Squeeze Theorem.

I haven't done many continuity proofs in multivariables yet, so I'd be glad if someone could check and correct me if I'm wrong.

**Edit:** For future reference, my proof does not work since the first inequality I established is plain wrong, considering that the term on the right can be negative.

Answer (score 2):

This function is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Consider the case where $x=y$ first, then $f(x,y) = |x|^3 \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Then consider the case where $x = y^\frac{1}{6}, y > 0$. In such case, $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{y^\frac 13 - y^\frac 76 + y^2} \rightarrow +\infty$ as $y \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Comment: The numerator $(y^\frac{1}{6})^2 \cdot y^3 \neq 1$.